# Which tense is correct? "Bob wanted to know if he is/was a father"

Tags: verbs, tenses, backshifting

Bob wants to know if he is a father or not. A day later, Bob learns that he's a father. Then three years pass.

Now which of the following is correct and why?

> 1. Three years ago, Bob wanted to know if he **is** a father or not.
> 2. Three years ago, Bob wanted to know if he **was** a father or not.

Any help is appreciated! But I would greatly appreciate an explanation with your answer. Thank you!

Comment: "Then three years passes." should be "Then three years pass.", because years is plural.

Comment: Definitely "was".  Because the time at which he wanted to know his paternity/fatherhood was in the past. So "was". And sorry, but I couldn't resist: https://youtu.be/vt2i0ts-uck?t=2s

Comment: @Javatasse *Three years*, like *ten dollars*, can be considered as a single unit, and as such can take a singular verb. This topic has been beaten to death on this site.

Comment: @Knotell Is this topic you refer to the topic of synesis, aka "notional agreement"?

Comment: I would use "whether" instead of "if".

Comment: Is there a reason there has been so many downvotes here? The answers are legitimate and can't see any other viable one. I don't think this reputation-assassination inspires contributions.

Answer (score 1):

**Was**

You're talking about an event in the past since "wanted" is in the past.  Three years ago is not the present, so "is" can't be used.  It's that simple.

Comment: No idea why this was downvoted, it's the only correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

No matter what, it will be the past-tense.  Three years ago, Bob wanted to know if he **was** a father or not. Not because it is "three years ago" but because of the reported speech -- "he **wanted** to know."

I asked him "**Am** I eligible?"

I wanted to know if I **was** eligible.

meta: This question may better be asked on [ell.se]

Comment: I see. Interesting.

Comment: There is no reported speech in the question.

Comment: This is a form of subjunctive *mood*, not tense, and is not limited to reported speech. If it *was*, then tense agreement *would* still trump the present tense.

Comment: @vectory - This is *not* a form of the subjunctive mood.  "Was" doesn't appear in the subjunctive mood.  "Were" does.  This is using the past tense of what in present tense would be "He wants to know if he is the father."

Comment: Post the comments above, I'd say, make things clearer before down voting an answer. Good Luck and Thanks.

Comment: @vectory - Sorry, you've misunderstood something about how the subjunctive works in English.  Here's what *would* work for the subjunctive: *He wishes he were the king of the world.*  (Your second clause, *I would too if I were that rich* is fine.) Also note, there is no subjunctive in the question as written, and subjunctive wouldn't fit there.  OP is just asking whether to use present or past (*is* vs. *was*).

Comment: @aparente001 "I wish I was a little bit taller, I wish I was a baller, ..." (Skee-Lo - I wish) I don't know what that is, maybe ebonics dialect, but it's certainly not past tense. While the optative expressing wishes hasn't survived anywhere, *Let's go* surely would be one. OE used to make a difference with *se*, cognate to Ger *sei*, dubbed Konjunktiv 1 over here in contrast to Konjunktiv 2 *wäre*, many weak verbs don't exactly inflect for Konjunktiv 1 but simply look like the preterite; It's used primarily for indirect speech as well. Surely there is comparative literature about this.

Comment: @vectory - one more request.  Could you save the free association for your journals and letters to intimates?  I just cannot follow all the stuff that streams from your keyboard. // Look up what's already been written here about subjunctive.  "I wish I was a little bit taller" is the most common thing.  The people who use the subjunctive (I wish I were a little bit taller) are in the minority.  In English. // This site is about English.  It's not a site for looking at English through the lens of German.

Comment: Btw what does the FAQ say about down voting -- has anyone noted?

Answer (score -1):

Well...

English is a tricky bastard.

And either sentence is possible (i.e., grammatical), given the right circumstances.

Say the speaker (let's call him Sal) is narrating an event that takes place entirely in the past, that is, he's telling a story or relating an event in the present from the point of view that it is over and done with; in this case you get the more probable result that (2) is correct, precisely because it is past narration, or narration about the past.

On the other hand, for (1) to be correctly used, consider Sal to be a story-teller, but this time he is telling a story about the present, and in doing so he uses the historical present, also called the story-telling present. Then, Sal can spin off some thing like

> Three years ago, Bob wanted to know if he is a father or not. Today, Bob wants to know if he is an uncle or not.

Here, Sal switches midway through his first sentence from past narration to historical present. His use of *if he is a father or not* alerts the listener to this switch and prepares said listener for the present tense in his second sentence. The parallel use of present tense *is* in both sentences is important to Sal's story and it wouldn't carry the same force without it.

Which, once again, asking for analysis of individual sentences devoid of functional and/or communicative context as well as  perceived speaker's intention is chock full of problems and  hardly allows for how language is used.

Comment: I'd think in AmE, *anything* "is possible (i.e., grammatical)."